# Late 1980s series of "choose your own adventure" books about a time traveller

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, choose-your-own-adventure

I've checked some of the other questions about similar books involving time travel, but this series is different from those.

In the late 1980s I read a series of Choose Your Own Adventure-style books where you have a time machine. I believe the series was fairly short, certainly not involving 10s of books. The main element I can remember is that the headquarters of the people who had invented the time machine were inside the Eiger Mountain. I can only remember one plot point, in which one set of choices in one story leads you to be put into suspended animation in the past, you end up in a museum in the future (as people had thought you were a classical statue), and you step off your plinth only to be electrocuted by an anti-theft device.

I hope these few elements are familiar to someone. I'm sure I'll know the books when I see them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(novel_series) ?

Comment: Seems to fit Choose Your Own Adventure #1, Cave of Time, but that's not going to be it. (Note that if you had this particular book you would have believed it was a short series.) I'm wondering how exactly the question should be improved to exclude it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Falcon](https://gamebooks.org/Series/146/Show) series of six gamebooks is at least a partial match. As mentioned at that link, the readers plays a time-travelling special agent; and from my own memory, the headquarters is in some mountainous location.

Other potentially memorable items are:

- the distinctive name of a featured character: **Agidy Yelov**
- a scene where you have to cause [the death of Ögedei Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96gedei_Khan#Europe) and thus bring about the end of the Mongol invasion of Europe.
- > the fact that Yelov turns out to be bad

Comment: Yes! The cover image of book 1, showing domed time machine, shows me that this is exactly it. I haven't read these in years and I have such a nostalgic yearning for them. Thank you very much for pointing me to the right series.